# Subscribing additional method call for each method

Tags: c#

I have been trying to find a way to subscribe myself to each method call in the application.
What I am trying to do is be able to call a StartTimer when a method is called and a StopTimer when the method is finished.

The idea is that this can not be integrated in the curent source code it can only be used inside the UnitTests project.

I have been looking for this online but could not find anything related to this.This will not be used in the production code just for unit testing.I am hoping this can be achieved using reflection.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved or if any tool or library exists out there that can do this?

Comment: Why your unit tests rely on execution time?

Comment: We are interested to calculating how long each method takes to run to be able to better see where performance problems are present

Comment: why do you do that in unit tests then? You have performance issues - you take profiler and profile your code.

Comment: AFAIK Unit tests can only tell you if the behavior of code is as expected, performance isn't a concern for them and they might be orders of magnitude slower than a real execution (or simply take unpredictable lengths of time to complete). Also, using reflection would make the code even slower. Performance auditing is done through a profiler, as already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use postsharp OnMethodBoundaryAspect to add additional call before and after each method, there are many ways to control where it should be applied.

For e.g. below code will add those additional call to only pubic class and public method on the namespace "MyNamespace.*" and only in debug mode.

```
#if DEBUG 
[assembly: Trace( AttributeTargetTypes = "MyNamespace.*", 
    AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public, 
    AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public )] 
#endif
```

http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/examples/logging

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is a classical use case for [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).
There are multiple frameworks for this in .Net.
For example [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) and [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody).
Fody has a [MethodTimer](https://github.com/Fody/MethodTimer) module that you can easily integrate using NuGet.

There may also be profilers (e.g. [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)) that allow automation (command line or API)

Comment: This are interesting solutions but I am not aloud to touch the production code I have to do all the work inside the unit test

Comment: Like i mentioned in my answer, you can use "#if DEBUG" then postsharp changes will be added only during debug build and in release build there will be no modification. It requires to add an additional reference and small change in assembly info file, no other changes needed.